# Embed Image in a XML entry

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to display text in following format in my web application dynamically

```
"Display the following image <image>"
```

I have a xml entry like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entry key="testDiv">Display the following image</entry>
```

What is the best practice to add the image next to the text. Is there a way i could do it by embedding it in xml or from javascript?

Thanks

Comment: How are looking to align the image and text?

Comment: Next to each other, on the same line

Answer (score 0):

try to use base 64 encoded image for embedding text inside xml

Comment: do you have any example ?

Comment: try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saeedsalehi/jh0pttxc/) , encode your image to base 64 inside of xml [see this link](https://www.opinionatedgeek.com/Codecs/Base64Encoder)